# ets:match does not return expected value

Tags: erlang, ets

I'm having trouble with ets:match. In the following code I expect the ets:match to return 1 found value, but none is returned. Why ?

```
1> T = ets:new(xxx, []).
16400
2> ets:insert(T, {a, b, c, d}).
true
3> ets:match(T, {'_', '_', '_', '_'}).
[[]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want [ets:match_object/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match_object-2) instead:

```
> ets:match_object(T, {'_', '_', '_', '_'}).
[{a,b,c,d}]
```

When using [ets:match/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match-2), the pattern should include some atoms like `'$1'`, `'$2'` and so on.  The result will be a list of lists, where each sublist will contain the corresponding elements in the order given by the magic atoms.  For example, to get the last three elements in reverse order:

```
> ets:match(T, {'_', '$3', '$2', '$1'}).
[[d,c,b]]
```

Since you didn't use any such atoms in your match, zero elements are returned for each match; thus the list containing one empty list, `[[]]`.